# How to return the Church number

Tags: scheme, racket, church-encoding

I want to change decimal encoding number to chruch encoding number ?

```
(define (encode n)
  (lambda(fn)(lambda(x) (funPower (fn n)x))))
```

What's wrong with my code? Thank you.

Comment: You have `(funPower f 1)` = `f`, so `(encode 1)` = `(lambda (fn) (lambda (x) (fn 1)))`. Doesn't look right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Data struct and hardware decided church number is so so slower than binary number.

```
#lang racket
; church-number->n : procedure -> number
(define (church-number->n cn)
  ((cn (λ (x) (+ 1 x))) 0))

; n->church-number : number -> procedure 
(define (n->church-number n)
  (local [(define zero (λ (f) (λ (x) x)))
          (define add-1
            (lambda (n)
              (lambda (f)
                (lambda (x) (f ((n f) x))))))
          (define (aux n cn)
            (if (= 0 n)
                cn
                (aux (- n 1) (add-1 cn))))]
    (aux n zero)))


;;; TEST
(church-number->n (n->church-number 101)) ; 101
(church-number->n (n->church-number (church-number->n (n->church-number 666)))) ; 666

; still slow than binary number
(church-number->n
 (compose (n->church-number 100) (n->church-number 5))) ; 500

(define mult
  (lambda (m)
    (lambda (n)
      (lambda (f)
        (lambda (x)
          ((m (n f)) x))))))

(church-number->n ((mult (n->church-number 100)) (n->church-number 5))) ; 500
```

Answer (score 1):

You wrote

```
(define (encode n)
  (lambda(fn)(lambda(x) (funPower (fn n)x))))
```

Assuming you already have `funPower` defined such that

```
((funPower fn n) x) = (fn (fn ( ... (fn x) ... )))
;;                    \____n_times____/
```

(as we saw several such questions here recently),
what you meant was

```
(define (encode n)
  (lambda (fn)
    (lambda (x) ((funPower fn n) x))))
```

i.e. the *encoded `n`* is a *curried function*, expecting `fn` and then `x`, such that

```
(((encode n) fn) x) = ((funPower fn n) x)
                    = (fn (fn ( ... (fn x) ... )))
;;                    \____n_times____/
```

So it was just a matter of proper parenthesization.

That definition could be tweaked for efficiency though, as

```
(define (encode n)
  (lambda (fn)
    ((lambda (g)
       (lambda (x) (g x)))
     (funPower fn n))))
```

calculating the `(funPower fn n)` in advance of receiving the `x`, instead of doing that each time anew for each new `x`, which is certainly wasteful; which is self-evidently equivalent to

```
(define (encode n)
  (lambda (fn)
    ((lambda (g)
       g)
     (funPower fn n))))
```

and, further, to just

```
(define (encode n)
  (lambda (fn)
    (funPower fn n)))
```

`funPower` itself too could be made more efficient than just linear composition of `n` items `fn`, by application of the *exponentiation by repeated squaring*.